# What is meant by a "closed point" of a rigid analytic space?

Tags: rigid-analytic-geometry

This is perhaps a naive question, but I have seen some authors (such as Mazur, Kisin) use the term of a "closed point" for (classical) rigid analytic spaces. I am slightly confused as to what this actually means, even in the case of affinoids.

First, because by definition the set of points of an affinoid is the set of maximal ideals of its ring of functions, so it seems like (taking the analogy from schemes) every point should be closed (there are no points corresponding to other ideals).

And second, because one usually thinks of a rigid analytic space as only having a G-topology, and not an actual topology.

Also, in introductory texts (such as in the BGR nonarchimedean analysis book, or in Conrad's AWS notes) the term "closed point" does not seem to be used for an analytic space.

Could someone clear up the confusion for me?

Thanks!

Comment: Some context might help but: a) if you think about the adic space instead of the rigid space it has non-closed points (it's locally spectral, even), b) "closed point" might just mean a point of the topos of the G-topology corresponding to a maximal ideal as you desire

Comment: Thanks. I don't what a topos is, but the use of the term "closed point" definitely does not only appear when there are adic spaces around. For example, in the Eigencurve paper of Coleman and Mazur, they talk about the local ring of a closed point of an affinoid. But maybe they just mean to say that it's a maximal ideal of the underlying ring